# How to have all the inputs on the same line C++

Tags: c++, input, cin

I was asked to enter an hour and a minute on the same line. But when I enter the hour, it automatically goes to a new line, and I'm only able to enter the minute on the next line. However, I want to enter the hour and minute on the same line with a colon between them. It should look like this

> ```
> Time: 4:54
> ```

But my code produces this:

> ```
> Time: 4
> ```
>
> 54

```
cout << "\n\tTime: "; 
cin >> timeHours;
cin.get();
cin >> timeMinutes;
```

Comment: The posted code looks good to me. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with sample input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior depends on the input provided by the user.

Your code works as you want, if the user would enter everything (e.g.`14:53`) on the same line and press enter only at the end:

[Demo 1](http://ideone.com/88N9zq)

Now you can have a better control, if you read a string and then interpret its content, for example as here:

```
string t; 
cout << "\n\tTime: "; 
cin >> t;
stringstream sst(t);
int timeHours, timeMinutes;
char c; 
sst>>timeHours>>c>>timeMinutes;
```

[Demo 2](http://ideone.com/D3e0mV)

Answer (score 3):

You can do that as the following :

```
cin >> timeHours >> timeMinutes;
```

according to the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/) :

> the user is expected to introduce two values, one for
>   variable a, and another for variable b. Any kind of space is used to
>   separate two consecutive input operations; this may either be a space,
>   a tab, or a new-line character.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input;
    char symbol;
    int hour, min;
    cout << "Time: ";
    getline(cin, input);
    stringstream(input) >> hour >> symbol >> min;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be like this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{ int hour,minute;
cin>>hour>>minute;

cout<<"Time:"<<hour<<":"<<minute;
return 0;

}
```