# how to terminate cin taking a value on space intead of carriage return because it cause the program to go to next line and I want it on the same line?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int int1, int2;
    std::cout << "Enter pair of integer e.g (Integer1,integer2)  : ";
    std::cout << "( ";
    std::cin >> int1;
    std::cout << ",";
    std::cin >> int2;
    std::cout << " )\n\n";
}
```

> Actual output: Enter pair of integer e.g(Integer1,integer2)  :(1
>
> ,2
>
> )
>
> *I want to cin both value on same line.*
>
> desire output: Enter pair of integer e.g(Integer1,integer2)  :(1,2)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to have all the inputs on the same line C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37647249/how-to-have-all-the-inputs-on-the-same-line-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int int1, int2;
    std::cout << "Enter pair of integer e.g (Integer1,integer2)  : ";
    std::cin >> int1 >> int2;

}
```

If you type two numbers without a space, you will get their values. You lose the "()", but do you really need them?

Here's an example where the user is required to type the pair in themselves. It's a bit flexible as they can type it in almost any way they choose. The only requirement is that there is a comma separating the numbers. It's missing a lot of validation that I would consider mandatory for this approach. Like determining if there are in fact numbers entered, the comma restriction is almost arbitrary, so it would need to go away as well. But this is enough code to get started.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int find_number(std::string str, int startIdx = 0)
{
    std::string digits("0123456789");
    int numStart = str.find_first_of(digits, startIdx);

    return std::stoi(str.substr(numStart));
}

int main()
{
    std::string numPair;
    std::cout << "Enter pair of integer e.g (Integer1,integer2)  : ";
    std::getline(std::cin, numPair);

    int firstNum = find_number(numPair);
    int commaLoc = numPair.find_first_of(",");
    int secondNum = find_number(numPair, commaLoc);

    std::cout << firstNum << '\n' << secondNum << '\n';
}
```

Per the question in your headline, `std::cin` stops on all whitespace, not just hitting the enter key. But you always have to hit Enter when you're finished with your input.

Comment: I Know this method you just coded. but it did not give what i wanted. I just wanted to make my output more expressive as we need to enter the numbers in pairs.I just wanted to know that there is anyway that we can get the output as mention .

Comment: It works. I don't know what you mean. If I type `75 42` with a space between the numbers, the integers are saved in their respective variables. The user either must type the full pair themselves `(num1, num2)` and you then have to parse the string, which is overall pointless, or you want a library like ncurses because `cin` and `cout` don't behave the way you want them to. Because it's not output that you're tying to make more expressive, it's input.

Comment: okay thanks man .i just wanted to know is it possible to take input like that.and You gave me the answer.